# iPod isn't showing up in windows 8 nor iTunes?

Tags: windows-8, itunes, ipod-touch

Before I say anything, my iPod screen is broken so I cannot see nor use the screen, only voice commands.

Anyway, I downloaded iTunes and imported all my music.
I got ready to sync, so I connected my iPod.  My computer made the device connected tone.
However, my iPod is not showing up in My Computer, nor in iTunes. How can I sync my iPod?

I'm using Windows 8 and an iPod touch 4.

update: I updated the driver software, my ipod now charges.  it does not show up in My Computer.  However, when I open iTunes, it states that my iPod is locked.  The computer used to previously sync this ipod is... well its now scrap metal.  Seeing as how my screen is broken, is there a way i can unlock it without entering my passcode on my ipod?

I HAVE authorized this computer with iTunes store

Comment: Are you sure it still functions because it sounds like its not.

Comment: iPhone plays a tone when it starts to charge. I don't know if iPod does that too, but if it does, does it play the tone? I mean, does the iPod know it is connected to a power source? Anyhow, I suggest trying to connect it to another USB port.

Comment: What does the device manager show? It may not have installed the drivers, or the battery is really dead and it needs to charge a bit before anything can really happen.